# Remove anagrams from a string vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program which removes all anagrams from vector. I sorted them alphabetical and i put them in a class, hopefully it would be easier to delete de anagrams, but it didnt actually helped.

```
INPUT:{"have","ahve","frame","avhe","farme","code","abc","ehav"}
OUTPUT:{"code","abc"}
note- all words are lowercase
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Fraza{
    string word;
    string word_alph;
    Fraza(){};
    Fraza(string words,string word_alph){
        this->word=move(word);
        this->word_alph=move(word_alph);
    }
    void printverify() const{
        cout<<word<<" is sorted "<<word_alph<<endl;
    }
    void print() const{
        cout<<word<<endl;
    }


};

int main() {
    Fraza fraza [100];
    vector<Fraza>text;
    string tmp;
    string tmpa;
// i am taking the input, store the words temporary in tmpa and sort tmpa, then i put them in struct
    while(cin>>tmp){
        tmpa=tmp;
        sort(tmpa.begin(),tmpa.end());
        text.emplace_back(Fraza(tmp,tmpa));

    }
// trying to delete the words

for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<text.size();j++) {
        if (fraza[i].word_alph==fraza[j].word_alph) {
            text.erase(text.begin()+i);
            text.erase(text.begin()+j);
        }
    }
}
    for(const auto& it:text)
        it.printverify();
    for(const auto& it:text)
        it.print();


    return 0;
}
```

so far i know that it might work comparing the sorted word. If 2 words are the same, i should try delete the words on the specific position

Comment: You didn’t explain what is not working, but what happens to the word at index `j` when you remove a word at index `i` and `i < j`?

Comment: You are sorting the vector on each input... except for the last. that seems weird (and inefficient)

Comment: if you use a `std::set` instead of `std::vector` you need not erase anagrams, because sorted anagrams are equal strings and arent inserted into a `std::set<std::string>`

Comment: if two words are anagrams you want to remove both? Please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i included input and output.

Comment: `emplace_back` forwards its arguments to a constructor - you only need `text.emplace_back(tmp,tmpa);`. Your variant creates the copy you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There are several bugs:

- The `Fraza` constructor has a parameter called "words" that you don't use; `this->word = std::move(word)` moves from the member to itself. (Get familiar with the initialization list).
- You have both an array `fraza` and a vector `text`. All the words are in `text`, but you compare the (empty) strings in `fraza`.
- After you have erased the `i`:th string, the previously `j`:th string is the `j-1`:th string.

Fixing these bugs makes your program *almost* work, except it leaves behind one copy of anagrams that occur an odd number of times (since you remove an even number of them, there will always be one left).

I would approach this with a table.

First, encapsulate the sorting and give `Fraza` an ordering that makes anagrams equivalent:

```
class Fraza
{
public:
    Fraza(const std::string& w)
        : word(w), sorted(w)
    {
        std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());
    }

    bool operator< (const Fraza& other) const
    {
        return sorted < other.sorted;
    }

    const std::string& str() const { return word; }
        
private:
    std::string word;
    std::string sorted;
};
```

Then use `std::map` as a counting table:

```
int main()
{
    // Count the words.
    std::map<Fraza, int> table;
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> word)
    {
        table[word] += 1;
    }
    // Print the unique ones.
    for (const auto& it: table)
    {
        if (it.second == 1)
        {
            std::cout << it.first.str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any posibility to not use maps ? Teacher wont allow this, and  to be honest ,i dont understand this concept well.

Comment: Special restrictions should be mentioned in the question.